# How do I reduce the nex lines of Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, case

```
    def route_action(action)
    case action
    when 1 then @meals_controller.add
    when 2 then @meals_controller.list
    when 3 then @meals_controller.edit
    when 4 then @meals_controller.delete
    when 5 then @customers_controller.add
    when 6 then @customers_controller.list
    when 7 then @customers_controller.edit
    when 8 then @customers_controller.delete
    when 0 then stop
    else
      puts "Please press 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 0"
    end
  end
```

So I want to reduce this case when is there another way of implementing this?

Comment: I would keep what you have. It reads well, performance is not an issue, testing is straightforward and the chances of introducing an error when choice are added,  removed or reordered are less than if using code that  more complex.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You are so right. Especially when looking at the accepted answer. Most of the time it is more important than code is easy to read and to understand than that it is short. The next developer who is looking at this method because it needs to be changed or updated will thank you.

Comment: I agree with @CarySwoveland btw. My answer below is only relevant if you plan on expanding this to a lot of extra cases and/or intend to expand the use to maybe a few other applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heads up, this is just a general suggestion on how to use a bit of Ruby meta-programming to get out of the tangle of having to declare a long method full of case business logic. It won't fit perfectly and will need to extra work to do, for instance, the "quit" logic.

Also. I'll reiterate what's been said in one of the direct answers to the post. Your `case` solution is VERY clear. It's good code and we shouldn't jump into messier thing just to comply to the all-mighty gods of the ruby stylesheet guidelines. Just because a method is under 10 lines, it doesn't make it automatically better than an 11 (or... hell 40) lines one.

Now...

#### Here's a meta-programming suggestion...

You can define a hash on a constant to hold the variables needed for the business logic:

```rb
ROUTES = [
  { action: :add,  controller: :meals, description: "Add a meal" },
  { action: :list, controller: :meals, description: "List all meals" },
  { action: :add,  controller: :customers, description: "Add a customers" },
  { action: :list, controller: :customers, description: "List all customers" },
]
```

You can then create a method that dispatches the user to the correct controller action using the hash info:

```rb
def dispatch(action_index)
  route_action     = ROUTES[action_index][:action]
  route_controller = ROUTES[action_index][:controller]
  instance_variable_get("@#{route_controller}_controller").send(route_action)
end
```

It's very easy with the hash to iterate over it to display the route descriptions:

```rb
def display_options
  ROUTES.each_with_index do |route, index|
    puts "#{index + 1}. #{route[:description]}"
  end
end
```

You can at some point in your code dispatch the user to the relevant controller action with `dispatch(gets.chomp.to_i - 1)`.

Cool thing about the hash is that you can always add more routes to it by just adding a single line.

Comment: Seems to fail to take into account out of range (in the original post) e.g. less than 0 or greater than 8, as well as the fact that 0 is intended to be `stop`?

Comment: Indeed I didn't take everything into account. It's just a general suggestion on how to use a bit of meta-programming to manage a growing router with extra controllers and actions. I'll add that as a warning to the answer.

Comment: Thanks pana caio, congrats for 1 year

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to have an array of message names to send based on the `action` input which is used as an index, and by determining which controller to send to by dividing by `5`. Inputs from `1` to `4` will yield `0`, while `5` to `8` will yield `1`.

```
def route_action
  actions = [:add, :list, :edit, :delete]

  case action
    when 1..8 
      controller = action / 5 < 1 ? @meals_controller : @customers_controller
      msg = actions[(action - 1) % 4]
      controller.send(msg)
    when 0 
      stop
    else
      puts "Please press 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 0"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
CASES = [@meals_controller, @customers_controller].product([:add, :list, :edit, :delete])

def route_action(action)
  if action > 0
    selected = CASES[action-1] # something like [:@meals_controller, :add]
    if selected
      selected.first.send(*selected.last)
    else
      puts "action number too large"
    end
  elsif action == 0
    stop
  else # Do we have to catch this?
    puts "action number negative" # programming error?
  end
end
```

Comment: A few issues with this code: 1) `CASES[0] #=> [:@meals_controller, :add]`. This action would be unreachable under the provided code. 2) `:@meals_controller.send(:add) #=> NoMethodError` because `:@meals_controller` is a `Symbol` not an instance_variable.

Comment: Thanks! That's why I love code reviews. Tried to fix it - would you mind having a look?

Comment: `controller` is undefined (I overlooked this the first time) maybe you meant `controller, selected = CASES[action-1]`? The only other concern is just whether or not the instance variables `@meals_controller` and `@customers_controller` can be known at the time of constant creation but even from the OP that is discernible.

Comment: @engineersmnky: Thank you again! I don't know how the variable `controller` slipped into my code. Must have happened when transfering the code from irb, where I used different naming anyway. I now changed it in the way I **originally** intended it, to stress that we are dealing here with controller-method-pairs, but of course your idea to name them explicitly would also work, and be even more legible if we plan to use that individual parts of the actions later on.